# I want to display only Upcoming recurrence events from calendar list

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, sharepoint-calendar

here I tried something but that's not up to the mark

 `objQuery.Query = @"<Where><DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><FieldRef Name='EndDate' /><FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value></DateRangesOverlap></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EventDate' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>";`
it shows result like below snippet
[image]
Events in Calendar List are as below Snippet
[image]

Here I only want to display future recurrence events ,so how can i achieve that,please help 
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by applying below code

```
        using (SPSite spsite = SPContext.Current.Site)
            {
                using (SPWeb web = spsite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists["CalenderList"];
                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                    query.ExpandRecurrence = true;
                    query.CalendarDate = DateTime.Now;
                    query.Query = @"<Where><DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><FieldRef Name='EndDate' /><FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Week /></Value></DateRangesOverlap></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EventDate' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>",
                    ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><FieldRef Name='EndDate' /><FieldRef Name='fRecurrence' /><FieldRef Name='RecurrenceData' /><FieldRef Name='Location' />",
                    SPListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(query);
                    foreach (SPListItem items in listItems)
                    {
                         DateTime Checkdate = DateTime.Parse(item["EventDate"].ToString().Trim());
                         DateTime CurrentDate=DateTime.Now;
                         if (Checkdate.Date > CurrentDate.Date)
                         {
                            Console.WriteLine(items[3].ToString());                   
                            Console.ReadLine();
                         }
                   }
               }
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

Valid values for `DateRangesOverlap` are `<Year>`, `<Month>`, `<Now>`.

If you want to get future recurrence events for single month than use `<Month>`.

If you want to get future recurrence events for entire year than use `<Year>`.

**I assumed here in below updated query that you need current month's results for recurrence events.**

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.ExpandRecurrence = true;
query.CalendarDate = new DateTime(2008,9,1);
query.Query = "<Where><DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\" /><FieldRef Name=\"EndDate\" /><Value Type=\"DateTime\"><Month /></Value></DateRangesOverlap></Where>";
```

Comment: yes that's true,and i tried the same query but tha is returning all recurrence events of the month ,means it  shows expired events as well,which i dint want

Comment: Try adding two lines mentioned in my updated code above the query & try it

Comment: Thank you for ur kind help but unfortunately the result is still same